# how to add class to the last two TRs and apply style to the TDs inside those TRs

Tags: jquery

I am trying to 
1) add a class to the last two TRs of every table on the page
2) and also style the 1st, 2nd, 5th and 8th TD of those two TRs.

The below piece of code doesn't seem to be working.

```
  var rowCount = $('table tr').length;
$('table tr').eq(rowCount - 1).addClass('myClass');
$('table tr').eq(rowCount - 2).addClass('myClass');
```

Thanks

BB

Answer (score 3):

To add a class to the last two rows of each table you could use:

```
$('table').each(function () {
    $(this).find('tr').last().addClass('red').prev().addClass('red');
});
```

And to add a class to the last two rows of each table and to specific columns of each of those rows you'd use:

```
$('table').each(function () {
    $(this).find('tr').last().addClass('myClass')
    .find(':nth-child(1)').addClass('myClass').parent()
    .find(':nth-child(2)').addClass('myClass').parent()
    .find(':nth-child(5)').addClass('myClass').parent()
    .find(':nth-child(8)').addClass('myClass').parent()
    .prev().addClass('myClass')
    .find(':nth-child(1)').addClass('myClass').parent()
    .find(':nth-child(2)').addClass('myClass').parent()
    .find(':nth-child(5)').addClass('myClass').parent()
    .find(':nth-child(8)').addClass('myClass').parent();
});
```

This last bit seems kind of messy. I assume there's a better way to do it, but this works.

Comment: here is what i found: $('table tr:last-child td:nth-child(1)').css('background-color', '#ffa'); changes the color of 1st td of the last TR of every table on the page. But, $('table tr:last-child').addClass('myClass'); would not work. i tried ur code still it won't add the class.

Answer (score 2):

Try slicing it ?

```
$(function() {
    $('table tr').slice(-2).addClass('last_two');

    $('table tr').eq(0).addClass('first')
           .end().eq(1).addClass('second')
           .end().eq(4).addClass('fifth')
           .end().eq(7).addClass('eight');
});
```

Comment: Well, is it an ID, or is'nt it ??

Comment: @BumbleBee - and I edited the answer, and remember the document ready function ?

Comment: @adeneo added in the missing `.` before end() :)

Comment: @wirey - Thanks, gee! Missed those?

Comment: I tried ur code but no luck.  here is what i observed :   $('table tr:last-child td:nth-child(1)').css('background-color', '#ffa');  changes the color of 1st td of the last TR of every table. But,  $('table tr:last-child').addClass('myClass');  would not work.